# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in child element in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this array in my child element

```
  @Input() listAnswer: any;

  changestyle(event)
  {
   let activeSpan = event.target;
   this.listAnswer.push(activeSpan.innerText.trim());
  }
```

passing this variable from parent component

```
<app-child [listAnswer]="listAnswer"></app-child>
```

but getting this error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

the same code was working on main component.

Any suggestion Thanks

Comment: You declared the listAnswer but did you initialize it? e.g. listAnswer = new ListAnswer [] of values:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your listanswer needs to be declared as an array:

```
@Input listAnswer: any[];
```

and in your parent component also needs to have its listAnswer property be an array type.

Comment: Thanks we have to initialize in parent component because if i have to share this variable in both the component initializing the array in child component will overwrite the array values

Comment: yep caught it after answering. has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialized some value during the listAnswer input declaration on your component.ts. Like below:

```
  @Input() listAnswer: any[]=[];
```

Comment: Could additionnaly type it as `string[]`

Comment: Yeah. It can be a string array also.